# Alinear pirámide de asteriscos Javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas noches y como siempre, gracias de antemano. Hice un ejercicio para escribir con asteriscos en forma piramidal (lo explico mejor en este fragmento de código )

```js
function pyramid(numPisos) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numPisos; i++) {
    let piso = '';
    for (let j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
      piso = piso + '*';
    }
    console.log(piso)
  }
}

pyramid(5);
```

y lo siguiente que quiero hacer es que esta misma pirámide se alinee a la derecha, en vez de a la izquierda como está ahora. Sé que necesito otro bucle for* entre los dos existentes, pero tras probar más de 100 formas lo único que consigo es que la pirámide tenga en cada línea 5 espacios antes de escribir el asterisco.Es decir, solo consigo desplazarla hacia la derecha pero no cambio su alineación.
Por si doy lugar a muchas dudas, mi objetivo sería dejarla así:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Siguiendo tu ejemplo, puedes realizarlo como mencionas, agregando otro for.

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
    function pyramid(numPisos) {
      for (let i = 0; i < numPisos; i++) {
        let piso = '';
        for (let j = 1; j < numPisos - i; j++) {
          piso = piso + ' ';
        }
    
        for (let j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
          piso = piso + '*';
        }
        console.log(piso);
      }
    }
    
    pyramid(5);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que necesitaba para tenerlo claro, un saludo

Answer (score 5):

ciertamente una de las soluciones es agregar un tercer bucle para determinar el número de espacios en blanco que deben existir para desplazar el asterisco a la derecha y por ende, conseguir que la pirámide esté alineada a la derecha, cabe mencionar que el resultado se verá bien siempre y cuando se imprima usando fuente monoespaciada (como la consola del navegador). Anexo el código con la solución a tu pregunta. Saludos

```js
function pyramid(numPisos) {
  /* Espacios que se debe empujar el asterisco*/
  let spaces = numPisos - 1;
  
  /* Recorrer cada piso */
  for (let i = 0; i < numPisos; i++) {
    let piso = '';
    
    /* Agregar el número de espacios*/
    for (let j = 0; j < spaces; j++) {      
      piso += ' ';
    }
    
    /* Agregar el número de asteriscos */
    for (let k = 0; k <= i; k++) {      
      piso += '*';
    }
    
    /* Mostrar espacios y asteriscos por piso*/
    console.log(piso)
    
    /* El siguiente piso tendrá un espacio menos */
    spaces--;
  } 
}

pyramid(5);
```

Comment: de las respuestas que hay, esta es la menos optima, y me parece una copia de la de Jemonge

Comment: Si, veo que ya hay mejores respuestas, ¡enhorabuena! Por cierto no me he fijado que había una respuesta similar, no recargué el sitio antes de publicar. Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacerlo con un for, un metodo de javascript que se encarga de repetir la cadena vacia con [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart) luego concatenas la otra codena con la cantidad de *

```js
function pyramid(numPisos) {

 
  for (let i = 1; i <= numPisos; i++) {
    let piso = ''.padStart(numPisos - i, " ").concat("".padStart(i, "*"))
    console.log(piso)
  }
}

pyramid(5);
```

cambiamos el orden de la cadena para generar el arbol, te invito a jugar con este metodo

```js
function pyramid(numPisos) {

     
      for (let i = 1; i <= numPisos; i++) {
        let piso = ''.padStart(i, "*").concat("".padStart(numPisos - i, " "))
        console.log(piso)
      }
    }

    pyramid(5);
```

Comment: Mil gracias, me habéis sido de gran ayuda. Probaré a hacer más variantes para tenerlo totalmente claro. Un saludo

Comment: genial, ten en cuenta que esta respuesta solo hace una iteracion y juega con los metodos del string, su eficiencia algoritmica es de O(n), mientras que la otra es de  O(n^3), @BraisCaloto, por cierto te invito a hacer el [tour] ganaras algunas medallas!

Comment: Ciertamente 1 for es mejor que 2, y mucho mejor que 3

Answer (score 0):

Un for() y [repeat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_repeat.asp)

```js
function pyramid(numPisos) {
  for(let x = 1; x <= numPisos; x++){
    console.log(' '.repeat(6 - x) + '*'.repeat(x))
  }
}
pyramid(5);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Las otras respuestas son más entendibles que esta (¿qué es ese número mágico "6"?) Pulsa en [edit] y explica qué hace este código. Lee [answer].